# Can anyone figure out a fix for this MongoDB syntax error: illegal character @(shell):1:19?

Tags: mongodb, terminal

I'm setting up a new database in MongoDB I just created a new database(library) and collection(inventory). I am now trying to add a document to the collection but I can't figure out why I am getting the above syntax error for code below.

Quick description of the structure of the database, each document is an author, each author can have a number of books and each book can have a number of print runs.

```
db.inventory.insertOne(
{
    “Author": "Hadley", 
    "DOB": "10-11-80", 
    "Gender": "m", 
    "BankACC": 654321, 
    "Books": [
        { 
            "Title": "R for Data Science", 
            "YP": 2016, "ISBN": 4231-1234-90, 
            "Price": 10.99, 
            "Language": "English", 
            "PrintRuns": [
                { 
                    "Year": 2016, 
                    "NumPrinted": 500 
                }, 
                { 
                    "Year": 2017, 
                    "NumPrinted": 400 
                }
            ]
        }, 
        { 
            "Title": “Ethics in Data Science”, 
            "YP": 2013, "ISBN": 4255-1234-90, 
            "Price": 18.99, 
            "Language": "English", 
            "PrintRuns": [
                { 
                    "Year": 2016, 
                    "NumPrinted": 800 
                },
                { 
                    "Year": 2017, 
                    "NumPrinted": 1000 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
);
```

Comment: `“` in front of `Author` is not a `"`. That's an illegal character for a JavaScript object. Same things apply to various other places in the input. Comes out much clearer in a clearly formatted environment, so I suggest you invest in a decent code editor. You can just "copy/paste" text edited elsewhere directly into the `mongo` shell. Basically, see the formatting above for all the quotation errors. They clearly display here on Stack Overflow with the syntax highlighting

Comment: ISBN should probably be string as well `"4255-1234-90"`

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar Wrong again. It's just that there is no line break there and that's one of the parts that are correct.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, ok. Execute `insert({ "ISBN": 4255-1234-90 })`, see if `4255-1234-90` is inserted or something else (simply just so condescending)

Comment: @Neil Lunn thanks for the help, changing the quotes worked perfect it obviously was my text editor appreciate the advice also I will be investing in a decent code editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case the problem is not yet solved for you. Try to use tilt (`) instead of double quotes (").